# what is the difference between hitting `enter` after `then` and `;` in if condition

Tags: bash, if-statement, syntax

if i write this in a script it runs

```
if [[ 1 == 1 ]]
 then
   echo "true"
 fi
```

but if I tried to replace newline with ; when using an active shell i get syntax error

```
if [[ 1 == 1 ]]; then; echo "true"; fi
```

why?

what is the difference between hitting `enter` after `then` and `;`

Comment: There shouldn’t be a semicolon after `then`. It’s kind of like how `if (newline) [[ 1 == 1 ]] …` doesn’t mean the same thing as `if; [[ 1 == 1 ]] …`.

Comment: Technically you don't need `;` at all. You can use multiple lines even interactively.

Comment: Syntax of if: `if COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; [ elif COMMANDS; then COMMANDS; ]... [ else COMMANDS; ] fi` You can replace any space and semicolon with a line break. In contrast, you cannot replace every line break with a semicolon.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/281310/13792

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Compound-Commands) says:

> In most cases a list of commands in a compound command’s description may be separated from the rest of the command by one or more newlines, and may be followed by a newline in place of a semicolon.

[As well as](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs):

> The syntax of the `if` command is:
>
> ```
> if test-commands; then
>   consequent-commands;
> [elif more-test-commands; then
>   more-consequents;]
> [else alternate-consequents;]
> fi
> ```

(I believe the formatting in the above description (multiple lines, indentation) is for the benefit of the human reader, not part of the formal syntax. That is, `if test-commands; then consequent-commands; [elif more-test-commands; then more-consequents;] [else alternate-consequents;] fi` would have the same meaning.)

---

The initial statement says `;` in this description can be replaced by a newline, but not vice versa.

Instead it says you can optionally put newlines before and after the command lists, which are simply ignored.

---

Taking your example:

```
if [[ 1 == 1 ]]
 then
   echo "true"
 fi
```

Here we have *test-commands* of `[[ 1 == 1 ]]`. The syntax requires a `;`, but because of the "*may be followed by a newline in place of a semicolon*" rule, we're fine (there is a following newline).

For the `then consequent-commands;` part, we have

```
 then
   echo "true"
```

This is fine because the *consequent-commands* (i.e. `echo "true"`) "*may be separated from the rest of the command* [i.e. `then` in this case] *by one or more newlines*".

Again, the syntax requires a `;` next, but instead we use a newline, as permitted by the initial rule.

Then we reach the `fi` and we're done.

Comment: There is a formal grammar (for Posix shells) here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02 When you read that grammar you will see the non-terminals `linebreak` and `separator`; the first one is an *optional* series of newlines, and the second one is either a semicolon followed by a `linebreak` or a *mandatory* series of newlines. The bash grammar writes the first one as a newline and the second one as a semicolon (most of the time).